# Access scope data from two directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is just an abstract from my actually app.

I have `$scope.data` object from many parents up. Then in one child, there is this

`<input ng-model="data.number" calc="data" get-data='{"value":"data"}'>`

Basically:

- `calc` directive does some calculation on `data` object.
- `get-data` directive is even more abstract (because it supposed to work with multiple calculation like `calc`). So I want to just pass a JSON string into it to tell that `data` is where to get the actual data.

My `calc` is fine because I can access the `ng-model` using `require:"ngModel"`. But I am having trouble with `get-data` as I have no idea how to tell Angular that the string `"data"` means `$scope.data` at the parent. If you look at console log, there is no `data` showing up in the scope. I could dig through the parent to get it but again, I cannot make assumption that it's 1 level down or 10 levels down.

[image]

**QUESTION: How to convert "data" to reference the actual $scope.data object?**

http://plnkr.co/edit/TEJRv7svWw74her9srcS?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input ng-model="data.number" calc="data" get-data='{"value":"data"}'>
      <p> 
        {{ data }} 
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {number: 3};
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('calc', function() {
  return {
    // scope: {
    //   ngModel: '='
    // }, 
    require:"ngModel",
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log('calc');
      console.log(scope);
      console.log(ngModel);
      scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        newVal.multiply = newVal.number * 2;
        console.log('scope.$watch trigger');
        console.log(newVal);
      }, true);

      el.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log('calc blur');
        console.log(scope);
      });
    }
  }
});

app.directive('getData', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log('getData');
      console.log(scope);
      console.log(attrs); 
      var dataJSON = JSON.parse(attrs.getData);
      console.log(dataJSON.value); 
      scope.$watch('data', function() {
        // scope.data.multiply = scope.data.number * 2;
      }, true);

      el.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log('getData blur');
        console.log(scope);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

- Assume we don't know if `calc` is in the same element. There could be `calc1`, `calc2`,... out there
- I need to access the "reference" of `$scope.data` to watch it for change (on blur event). Not just the actual data content itself.

**UPDATE 2**

- `calc` may have isolated scope in the same DOM. If `getData` uses isolated scope too, it gives error `Multiple directives [], getData (module: plunker)] asking for new/isolated scope on`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use nested interpolation

```
get-data='{"value":{{data}}}'
```

This will make `data` to reference the actual `$scope.data` object within `get-data` directive.

[image]

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mVymX52Y7gl3gYktPoVN?p=preview)

**Update:**

If you want to access to the object reference to watch for a change in `data`, then you need to use `attrs.$observe`(`$watch` wont work) since `data` is bound to the *attribute* of your directive.

```
  attrs.$observe('getData', function(newVal) {
        console.log('NEW VAL: '+newVal)
  }, true);
```

Check updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mVymX52Y7gl3gYktPoVN?p=preview)

Comment: Please see my update. I need to access to the object reference to watch for change.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your getData directive declares an "isolated scope" by returning "scope attribute"  so its scope not uses scope of parent, but its own, if you really need an isolated scope and some data from parent to be in it you should use:

```
app.directive('getData', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '@'
    },
```

and "data" property from parent scope will be accesible in isolated scope as "data" property

Comment: I saw `data: undefined`. Plus I rather get the name of the object from attribute string.

Comment: So do not isolate scope,  remove `scope: {   ngModel: '=' }`  from `getData` directive   and  use  `scope.data.multiply = scope[dataJSON.value]['number'] * 2;`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It tried that and got undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here is some useful information about directives:

```
enter code here
```

http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

http://jonathancreamer.com/working-with-all-the-different-kinds-of-scopes-in-angular/

And my solution on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QoQcPSpkr0CnlZuT3tta?p=preview)

Comment: Please see my UPDATE 2 as I have a weird situation that other directives in the same DOM may have isolated scope.